# Lookup table does not work as expected

Tags: c++, arrays, aes, lookup

I have a weird issue while creating a substitution for AES encryption.
I use a lookup table, named SBox, to substitute the bytes in the string state (technically a vector, but it's irrelevant)

```
const vector<byte> SBox =
{
0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08,
0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a,
0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
};

void subBytes(vector<string>& state)
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        {
            state[i][j] = SBox[state[i][j]];
        }
    }
}
```

this does not work but if I use

```
state[i][j] = SBox[state[i][j]&0xff];
```

then everything magically works again. I thought a char was byte-sized, so AND'ing by 0xff had no influence. FYI I am running under 64-bit machine. This is a little bit annoying as I have to use a lot of lines like that in other functions. Can anybody explain why?  Is there another solution?

Comment: `char` is probably signed on your architecture.

Comment: in first line  byte means unsigned char. It was typedeffed previously

Comment: ok, thanks. What is the best way to keep it cross-platform?

Comment: The best way is `& 0xFF`.

Comment: Why not cast to unsigned char?

Comment: Also, in this particular, very specific case, I'd suggest using a plain array instead of a vector, e.g. `static byte const SBox[] = {...}`, purely for efficiency reasons.

Comment: `std::string` uses `char` which is a `signed` type with range -127 to 127, so assigning values outside of that range isn't valid. When you say it works, do you mean it compiles?

Comment: to avakar: implemented. @cdmh: thanks I was trying to look it up. That was definitely my problem. I guess another solution is to use unsigned char[] arrays instead of strings

Answer (score 1):

`state[i][j]` may return signed chars so if your character codes are larger than 7bits you are using negative index to `SBox[state[i][j]]`

Another thing:
if you have fix sizes for SBox and states: why not using std::array instead of vector?

`std::array<byte,256>` for SBox
and `std::array<std::array<char,4>,4>` for State.

Also you may use the size member of your vectors or arrays instead using magic number in your loop.